# Javascript - ¿Es posible seleccionar etiqueta según el CONTENIDO o mediante el FOR?

Tags: javascript, html

Django genera las etiquetas label automáticamente (sin ID, sin NAME, sin CLASS) así:

```
<label for="marca">Marca:</label>
```

¿Cómo se puede seleccionar según su contenido "Marca:" o según el for="marca"?

```
marca = document.getElementBy.innerHTML("Marca:");

marca = document.getElementByFor("marca");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes filtrar y seleccionar según el atributo `for` y en concencuencia su valor.

Es decir contamos con el método `querySelectorAll()` el cual nos permite recuperar N cantidad de elementos del *DOM* según la regla de selección que le pasemos como argumento.

Un ejemplo para tu caso sería:

- Tengo 4 labels
- Tres de esos labels tienen en el for un valor de *uno*
- Solo un label tiene el valor de *dos*
- Dentro de la función recuperamos solo aquellos que tienen en el for el valor uno
- Como recuperamos un conjunto de valores entonces debemos iterarlos
- Para obtener el texto de los valores iterados usamos la propiedad `innerText`

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <label for="uno">Uno</label>
    <label for="uno">Uno</label>
    <label for="uno">Uno</label>
    <label for="dos">Dos</label>
    <script>  
        let labels = document.querySelectorAll("label[for=uno]")
        
        labels.forEach((label) => {
          console.log(label.innerText)
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Por otro lado si solo es una etiqueta la que deseas recuperar entonces también tenemos otro método llamado `querySelector()` y la lógica del argumento pasado es la misma que la descrita mas arriba.

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <label for="uno">Uno</label>
    <label for="dos">Dos</label>
    <label for="tres">Tres</label>
    <label for="cuatro">Cuatro</label>
    <script>  
        let labels = document.querySelector("label[for=uno]")
        
        console.log(labels.innerText)
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Referencias**

- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias BetaM.